# Use Angular resolver to preload data from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

When loading the list view page for the first time all goes well, the list is populated and I can see all the data.
Then I navigate to another view to add new object, on save I'm redirected back to the list view.
When landing on the list view again I can see the list elements for a brief moment and then they dissapear till I refresh the page.

How should one use Angular resolvers with Firebase data fetching?

**My resolver**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CupListResolver implements Resolve < Cup > {

  constructor(
    private cupService: CupService
  ) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise < Cup > {
    let cups;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.cupService.getCups().subscribe(data => {
        cups = data.values();
        return resolve(cups);
      }, (error: any) => {
        return reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**My service**

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CupService {

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  getCups() {
    return this.afs.collection(`cups`, ref => ref.orderBy('color')).snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you attached `resolver` into some `path` and when you are "going back" (either by redirection or browser button), you don't destroy your component (your `resolver` isn't called once again). Propably you are changing only `children` component, when you are redirected. What you should do (or what i would do) is to add the object, which you are sending to backend to the array once you receive 20x response. That's why you are caching data in frontend layer. I wouldn't make another call to backed to fetch all data.

Comment: Actually my resolver is being called when I navigate back I can see log() statements coming from its invocation